# ASP.Net Core 3.0 "dotnet bundle" exited with code 150

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, dotnet-publish, dotnet-bundle

```
$ dn publish -f netcoreapp3.0 -c Release --no-restore --no-build src/Biz4x.Frontend.Web/
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  bower font-awesome    extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: font-awesome#5.0.8
  bower popper.js       extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: popper.js#v1.14.1
  It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
  The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview1-002111-00' was not found.
    - The following frameworks were found:
        3.0.0 at [/usr/share/dotnet-3.0.100/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

  You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

  The .NET Core frameworks can be found at:
    - https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
/usr/src/4xlabs/bz-frontend/src/Biz4x.Frontend.Web/Biz4x.Frontend.Web.csproj(89,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet bundle" exited with code 150.
```

Upgraded `BundlerMinifier.Core` to the latest version but to no avail!

```
 <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="3.0.415"/>
 <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="3.0.415"/>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/12886

Comment: Do you follow the instruction to install the [sdk/runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0).Also,refer to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7901#issuecomment-344715091)